# question about applications for downloading applications

Tags: download-speed, download-manager

Is there any free application that performs better than Ubuntu Software Center in downloading applications regarding the downloading speed and the ability to pause and resume? Or can I improve the performance of Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: The Software Centre should resume interrupted downloads without anything extra. You can speed it up using karel's link.